# candc:could not open model configuration file for reading:models/config

Tags: windows, nlp, nltk

I installed boxer, tool from C&C to convert CCG to DRS,  from http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/Installation

System - Windows 7 (64 bit)

But then after installing I am getting following error:

```
C:\Users\abcd\Documents\candc-1.00\bin>candc.exe --models models
candc:could not open model configuration file for reading:models/config
```

I did check http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/FAQ and I have an empty config file in models directory . But still it doesnt work

Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Which version did you download?

Comment: @Daniel models - version 1.02

Comment: I mean, which link did you use exactly from this page: http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/Download

Comment: @Daniel http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/download/candc/models-1.02.zip     
http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/download/candc/candc-mingw-1.00.zip

Comment: ok, I don't know why the config file in all models are empty. Post the answer if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing models directory from within the bin directory.
Execute the same command from outside bin .

Try

```
bin\candc.exe --models models
```

It should work fine now